# How to change object's layer at runtime in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime

I've got WallCreator script to place walls in Unity, and another one, WallCreatorSwitcher to turn WallCreator ON/OFF by checking the toggle. I also wanted to change wallPrefab's layer there by using `GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("LayerName");`, so when the toggle is checked (WallCreator ON) layer is "Ignore Raycast" - and it works, and if the toggle is unchecked (WallCreator OFF) layer is "Default" - but the problem is, it's not changing the layer in this case.

```
public class WallCreatorSwitcher : MonoBehaviour {

public Toggle toggle;
public Text text;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (toggle.isOn)
    {
        GetComponent<WallCreator>().enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("Wall Creator is ON");
        text.enabled = true;
        GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");

    }

    else
    {
        GetComponent<WallCreator>().enabled = false;
        Debug.Log("Wall Creator is OFF");
        text.enabled = false;
        GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");

       }

   }    

}
```

Comment: Presumably, the issue you're facing here is that `GetComponent<WallCreator>().enabled = false;` stops the component being interacted with at all, as a result you may have to turn it on, change the layer, and then turn it back off, alternatively make the layer switch before switching it off

Comment: Even when I deleted that `GetComponent<WallCreator>().enabled = false;` (so I'm able to place walls even when the toggle is unchecked) the layer is changing only for new objects. I mean, for example, I place wall1 with toggle ON - it's layer is "Ignore Raycast", then i switch toggle to OFF, place wall2 - it's layer is "Default", but the layer of wall1 doesn't change

Comment: I didn't realise you meant the walls placed before, that's a different issue entirely. The newer walls are in the default layer after it's changed - and that is because changing the prefab changes what is placed when you create a wall, not what's already there. To change the layer of ALL walls, you can do something like this (assuming the walls have the tag `wall`): `GameObject[] walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wall");` then you may manipulate them through a foreach loop

Comment: You should also post your `WallCreator` script and describe where each script is attached

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre yeah I probably presented my problem not correctly. Anyway, your answer helped a lot, it's working now, thank you

Comment: @artur47wien I'll add it as an answer in that case :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The newer walls, when placed, are in the `Default` layer after it's been changed in the prefab - and that is because changing the prefab changes what is placed when you create a wall, not what's already there. To change the layer of ALL walls, you can do something like this (assuming the walls have the tag wall)

```
GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
GameObject[] walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("wall");
foreach(GameObject wall in walls)
{
    wall.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
}
```

This will loop through every wall in the scene and change its layer to the one you want. It is also important that the `WallCreator` still has its property changed also, so that walls placed **after** this change, will remain on the new layer as opposed to the old one

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if you aren't referencing the gameObject of the wallPrefab, which could be the problem. Change:

```
GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
```

To:

```
GetComponent<WallCreator>().wallPrefab.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
```

Without seeing the other scripts, I can't be sure this will fix the problem though.

Comment: Read this part of their comment - "*I place wall1 with toggle ON - it's layer is "Ignore Raycast", then i switch toggle to OFF, place wall2 - it's layer is "Default", but the layer of wall1 doesn't change*", the layer **IS** changing, but they actually want the old walls to change layer

Comment: Gotcha, didn't see that. It's still good practice to reference the gameObject though. I'd say your comment above should do it, find all the object's and change their layer that way!

Comment: An added bonus of looping through them is also that you get the `GameObject` from the `FindGameObjectsWithTag`!

Comment: True that, less lines of code and you are sure that the layers have been changed. Nicely done, this is a very elegant solution.